# How to make my ListActivitity to be compatible with AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am building an Android app and I am trying to make it compatible with API level 10 using `AppCompat` library. Normal activities are no problem but when using what used to be `ListActivity` (now extends from `ActionBarActivitity`) I am getting problems with `setListAdapter(adapter)` and other `ListView` related methods.

What can I do to make my `ListActivitity` to be compatible with `AppCompat`?

Comment: You can use a `ListFragment` and extend `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: So I cannot use an Activity?

Comment: No use a `ListFragment`. You can do what you do with ListActivity except the fragment is attached to the activity which extends ActionBarActivity.

Comment: You can use `ListActivity` but do you want actionbar also??

Comment: Yes, I want both to use a Listview and actionBar.

Comment: then you need to use `ListFragment` with `AppCompat` as suggested in my post. or use ListView for the Activity and then set adapter to it no need for ListFragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ListFragment` from the support library http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html

You can use `AppCompact` and extend `ActionBarActivity`. In `ListFragment` you can use `setListAdapter(adapter)`.

If you don't want `ListFrament` you can have a `Listview` in activity layout, set the layout to the activity, initialize it in Activity and set adapter to `ListView`.

Comment: Ah sound good! This is my code for the activitity. I am not sure how to change it to fit your solution. http://pastie.org/private/85osmjwzsgaorlsmiexw

Comment: @JonathanClark have a lsitview in `activity_tasks.xml` like `<ListView android:id ="@+id/listview1 ...` then in activity   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);` then `Listview  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1)` then `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @JonathanClark let me know if you get stuck i will see if i can help further

Comment: I get no errors anymore but the listview is not populated with the API response like before. My code look like this now: http://pastie.org/private/ddbrsyqg9hertmumkkngw

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51267/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-jonathan-clark)

Comment: Thanks to @Raghunandan for brilliant help!